# How would i add an image above swipe tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs

How would i add an image above swipe tabs like in application Goffers.[image: Goffers]

And how would i change image when tab is changed like in their application?

Any tutorial or example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this according to my knowledge they have used **Extended Toolbar** introduced by Google in Google I/O 2014. You can surely apply image view in between a toolbar and change its image according to ViewPager currentItem using getCurrentItem() method of ViewPager.

Comment: Can you give me some tutorial or example?